# How to change value appcss in laravel

Tags: css, laravel, npm, sass, npm-run

I want to change background color in laravel page. Based on reference that i get. i should make a change in _variables.scss.

```
// Body
$body-bg: #f8fafc; --> i change it to #000

// Typography
$font-family-sans-serif: "Nunito", sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 0.9rem;
$line-height-base: 1.6;
........
```

In views file, i put code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ICan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css"> --> i enter this one
  </head>
  <body>
    @yield('content')
    @include('inc.sidebar')
  </body>
</html>
```

And then i do `npm run serve` in cmd
But nothing happen in my page. The background color doesn't change. Did i do something wrong?

Please help me. Thank you :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You arent doing anything wrong, simply missing a step.
Before serving the application, do this:

```
npm run dev
```

This will compile all of your scss files into your app.css file

however if you dont want to run this command every time you make a change in your scss file's, run the following:

```
npm run watch
```

This will watch for changes and run the compilation when a change occurs!

Comment: oh i'm sorry, i mean after edit files variables and views. i did 'npm run dev' not 'npm run serve'. But still nothing happen.

Comment: I truly apolagize, but im really not to sure what it is you are asking or trying to acheive. Can you possibly explain it differently or give a scenario of what you want to happen and when?

Comment: based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnvu1GpylP0 (at minutes 15.00 - 23.00) if i want to change my background color or make any custom with css, 1) i should install npm ---> 2) change value at file _variable.scss ($body-bg: #f8fafc; become $body-bg: #000;) ---> 3) put code <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css"> to views file ---> 4) did npm run dev on cmd. But after try that step from video, my background color didn't change. It still white, i want to change it become black.

Comment: I know this is a very simple solution but, have you tried clearing your browser's cache ?? Sorry for late reply btw!

Comment: It works :)) thank you~ I'm sorry for asking such a simple question. hehehe.. Have a good day!!

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to run `npm run serve` or any npm command for this.

just add another css file for your custom css or you can direct include styles in your blade.

you can find a blade in `layouts > app.blade.php` and then just put your style before closing head (`</head>`) like that:

```
   .container{
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

</head>
```

thats it